# Making Images side by side with the same width and height?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSS, 
I created HTML/CSS page and want to put 4 Images side by side 
with different width and height,
I want all of them to be same width and height,
because they don't look good with different width and height,
also the info doesn't appear on the same line because of that

CSS:

```
      p {
        line-height: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
     .clear {
        clear: both;
    }

    .wrapper {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0 10px;
        width: 940px;
    }       
    #primary-content {
        background-color: #f8fafa;
        padding: 20px 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #primary-content h3 {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
        width: 400px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #02b8dd;
        padding: 0 0 20px 0;
    }

    #primary-content images{
        margin: 20px 0;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="primary-content">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <article>
            <h3>Test</h3>

            <images>

                <p style="float:left; width: 23%; margin-right: 2%; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">
                    <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="img1" title="img1" style="width: 100%" /> info
                </p>


                <p style="float:left; width: 23%; margin-right: 2%; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">
                    <img src="images/img2.jpg" alt="img2" title="img2" style="width: 100%" /> info
                </p>



                <p style="float:left; width: 23%; margin-right: 2%; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">
                    <img src="images/img3.jpg" alt="img3" title="img3" style="width: 100%" /> info
                </p>


                <p style="float:left; width: 23%; margin-right: 2%; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">
                    <img src="images/img4.jpg" alt="img4" title="img4" style="width: 100%" /> info
                </p>


                <p style="float:left; width: 23%; margin-right: 2%; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">
                    <img src="images/img5.jpg" alt="img5" title="img5" style="width: 100%" /> info
                </p>


                <p style="float:left; width: 23%; margin-right: 2%; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">
                    <img src="images/img6.jpg" alt="img6" title="img6" style="width: 100%" /> info
                </p>

                <p style="float:left; width: 23%; margin-right: 2%; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">
                    <img src="images/img7.jpg" alt="img7" title="img7" style="width: 100%" /> info
                </p>

                <p style="float:left; width: 23%; margin-right: 2%; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">
                    <img src="images/img8.jpg" alt="img8" title="img8" style="width: 100%" /> info
                </p>

                <div class="clear"></div>
            </images>

        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: use display:flex;

Comment: Didn't work with @cup_of suggest

`.images img {
display:flex;
  float: left;
}`

https://jsfiddle.net/qe3m2ryv/4/

or my original https://jsfiddle.net/qe3m2ryv/3/ 

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do something like this:

```
<div class="images">
  <img src="http://www.immersion-3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg">
  <img src="http://www.immersion-3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg">
  <img src="http://www.immersion-3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg">
  <img src="http://www.immersion-3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg">
</div>

.images img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
```

give all your images a width and a height and float them left

jsFiddle Link

https://jsfiddle.net/qe3m2ryv/

Helpful information: No need to wrap each of your images in its own `<p>` tag in this situation. And the tag `<images>` doesn't exist. Use a div and give it a class called images.

Comment: Thanks 
but now the images is part of the footer,
also how I can put info for each image if I removed  <p> ?

Comment: sorry I did mistake, there was extra bracket,
works fine now, I just add 

   `margin-right: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;`

but I still don't know how to add info down each image if I remove the <p> tag.

thanks

Comment: I used this to add caption

`<a href="#">
        <img src=""> 
        <div class="caption">Caption 1</div>`
and
`#images{
    text-align:center;
}
#images a{
    margin:0px 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Put your 4 image in 4 div with the same fixed height and set width:100%; to your images. I think this solution work for you.

Comment: Can you write one example ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you want the images side by side with no margin in between or if you want the 2% margin in between so I did both in the same fiddle to show while working with your existing code:

what I did is removed the images tag and wrapped the images with a div and named the class "images" and styled it with display:inline-block. I also gave each image an id of "img" and styled with the desired width and height.

Please note that I gave the first image a margin-right of 0 so that they can be side by side with no gap and left the others at 2% to show you how each would look.

https://jsfiddle.net/ychpjxps/2/

Here is css:

```
.images{
  display:inline-block;
}


#img{
  width:75px;
  height:100px;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks
works fine, but the footer background color is white now, 
which supposed to be black

Comment: sorry I did mistake, there was extra bracket, works fine now.

Comment: thats good. don't forget to check the answer that worked for you so it can be marked as answered.

Comment: your answer and @cup_of works but I used his,
can't I accept more than one answer ?